# Can I make parameterized child route to components in lazy-loaded module?

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

My app.routing.module is as follows

```
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'reports', loadChildren: () => import('./reports/reports.module').then(m => m.ReportsModule)
```

AND the routes for lazy-loaded module is as follow

```
  path: '', component: ReportsComponent, 
  children: [
  { path : 'reports/:d_name' ,component: ReportdetailComponent },
```

Now how can i navigate to the paramaterized child route of the lazy-loaded module?

Answer (score 2):

The current route you wrote is `reports/reports/:d_name`

you should write your route that way in your child router

```
 path: '', component: ReportsComponent, 
  children: [
  { path : ':d_name' ,component: ReportdetailComponent },
```

edit :

```
{path: '', component: ReportsComponent, 
children: [{ path : ':d_name' ,component: ReportdetailComponent }] }]
```

when you add a children property to a current path, it means that it is the role of the parent component to handle the routing using a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
In this case the `ReportsComponent` need a router-outlet. It is usefull if you want a top component for each children and only modify a part of the page using the children.

```
 {  path: '', component: ReportsComponent}, 
 { path : ':d_name' ,component: ReportdetailComponent }
```

If you want only the main router of your app, you should avoid using children property.

It depends on your needs, if you provide more details, I could better understand the context.

Comment: I have just removed the auxilary <router-outlet> now when i navigate the pagenotfound component gets displayed!.I want the navigated child component displayed in the first <router-outlet>

Comment: may u please reply my above commented question?

Comment: @marioPetrovic may u please reply my above commented question?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking. Can you add some code to your question for that pleae?

Comment: @MarioPetrovic I want the router to display the child components of the lazy-loaded in the only one <router-outlet></router-outlet>in which the module lazy-loaded,where module lazy-loads and it's  children routes also gets rendered, when clicked.I mean to say that I only want to have one <router-outlet></router-outlet>.but I'am getting error

Comment: Well if you have one `<router-outlet>` you should be able to render any routed content. Did you import RouterModule in component where you use `<router-outlet>`?

Comment: Yes sir I have imported

Comment: Can you provide error message please or just ask another question and link it here so we have a clear example

Comment: app.routing.module.ts as 
` { path: 'reports', loadChildren: () => import('./reports/reports.module').then(m => m.ReportsModule) },{ path: '' , redirectTo : 'dashboard', pathMatch: "full"},  
  { path: '**' ,component: PagenotfoundComponent }`and app.component as `            <div routerLink="/reports" class="button" routerLinkActive="active" >Reports</div>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
` and report.routing.module as `{ 
  path: '', component: ReportsComponent,
  children: [{ path : ':d_name' ,component: ReportdetailComponent }]
}];`.

Comment: reports.html has another component inside  it which is shared module's component as `<app-datacard [depart]="depart"></app-datacard>
` the datacard.html it call function as `<div  #card (click)="hey(head.d_name)"></div>` which takes arguments and its datacard.component.ts it navigates `navigate(depart){
      this.router.navigate([depart], {relativeTo: this.route})
    }` now when i navigate  ,the `ReportdetailComponent` doesn't displays,but when i change the route configuration of the

Comment: `{path: '', component: ReportsComponent, children: [{ path : ':d_name' ,component: ReportdetailComponent }]
}];` to `{  path: '', component: ReportsComponent}, { path : ':d_name' ,component: ReportdetailComponent }` it works why?.and Again with `{path: '', component: ReportsComponent, children: [{ path : ':d_name' ,component: ReportdetailComponent }]`when i add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside the `report.component.html` it works and displays.why?

Comment: @MarioPetrovic here is new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62947496/can-anyone-tell-me-the-flow-of-router-that-how-it-treats-the-route-configuration

Comment: @mario i have questioned now..newly