# Can anyone tell me the flow of router that how it treats the route configuration and nested routes in lazy-loaded modules?

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, router, nested-routes

I want my lazy-loaded module in their  children components to be parameterizly loaded in one `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` .

My app.routing.module is

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'reports', loadChildren: () => import('./reports/reports.module').then(m => m.ReportsModule) }
  { path: 'patients', loadChildren: () => import('./patients/patients.module').then(m => m.PatientsModule) },
  { path: 'consultant', loadChildren: () => import('./consultant/consultant.module').then(m => m.ConsultantModule) },
  { path: 'store', loadChildren: () => import('./store/store.module').then(m => m.StoreModule) },
  { path: 'attendence', loadChildren: () => import('./attendence/attendence.module').then(m => m.AttendenceModule) },
  { path: '' , redirectTo : 'dashboard', pathMatch: "full"},  
  { path: '**' ,component: PagenotfoundComponent }
];
```

app.component.html is

```html
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div id="sidenav">
            <div id="logo"></div>
            <div routerLink="/dashboard" class="button" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</div>
            <div routerLink="/reports" class="button" routerLinkActive="active" >Reports</div>
            <div routerLink="/attendence" class="button"routerLinkActive="active">Attendence</div>
            <div routerLink="/patients" class="button"routerLinkActive="active">Patients</div>
            <div routerLink="/consultant" class="button"routerLinkActive="active" >Consultant</div>
            <div routerLink="/store" class="button"routerLinkActive="active">Store</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

and report.routing.module.ts is

```js
const routes: Routes = [
{ 
  path: '', component: ReportsComponent,
  children: [{ path : ':d_name' ,component: ReportdetailComponent }]
}];
```

`report.module.ts` has one shared module whose component `<app-datacard [depart]="depart"></app-datacard>`  is used and takes data where from parent and displays.As

```html
<p>reports works!</p>
<app-datacard [depart]="depart"></app-datacard>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div  #card (click)="navigate(head.d_name)" class="card_child" *ngFor="let head of depart ;index as i">
      <div  *ngFor="let data of head | keyvalue : returnZero">
          <div *ngIf="data.key == 'd_name' ; then thenB; else elseB"></div>
          <ng-template #thenB>
            <h2>{{data.value}}</h2>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #elseB>
            <div class="data_detail">
              <div >{{data.key}}</div>
              <div>{{ data.value}}</div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`data-card.component.ts` has router method as

```js
navigate(card){
   this.router.navigate([card], {relativeTo: this.route})
}
```

which navigates, but when i navigate to their children pagenotfound get displays.
AND
when I change the configuration order of
`report.routing.module.ts`  to

```js
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: ReportsComponent},
{ path : ':d_name' ,component: ReportdetailComponent }
];
```

it works but how?

**2**
AGAIN
When I add parameterized route in the  app.routing.module.ts
**and**

if add the parameterized route of `report.routing.module.ts` to `app.routing.module.ts`
as
report.module.ts

```js
const routes : Route = [{ path: '', component: ReportsComponent}];
```

to

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'reports', loadChildren: () => import('./reports/reports.module').then(m => m.ReportsModule) },
  { path : 'reports/:d_name' ,component : ReportdetailComponent },

  { path: 'patients', loadChildren: () => import('./patients/patients.module').then(m => m.PatientsModule) },
```

again works fine I'm not getting the flow router that gets the route configuration.
**3**
Is it necessary rule for router that to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` for the lazy-loaded's nested routes?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is good for the routing.

Just replace `this.route.navigate([card], {relativeTo: this.route})` to

```
this.route.navigate([card], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute})
```

So inject `ActivatedRoute` in your component and replace `this.route`.

For tour question why does it work, its because your `this.router` points to base route, and when you navigate to that with param with setup that does not have children, you actually point to correct routing.

As for the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, you need it in parent component to have your children render.

But if your have that error page not found than it should be `navigate` method problem

Comment: yes I did the same but ,i haven asked 3 questions? without answers

Comment: report.routing.module.ts is
`const routes: Routes = [
{ 
  path: '', component: ReportsComponent,
  children: [{ path : ':d_name' ,component: ReportdetailComponent }]
}];`
now when i navigate.`navigate(card){
   this.router.navigate([card], {relativeTo: this.route})
}`i get the PageNotfound component rendered.

Comment: it is because you have `relativeTo: this.route`, and i assume that you dont use ActivatedRoute. What are you injecting for `this.route`